# Differences between [NSArray arrayWithArray:] and [NSArray copy]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray

lately I work much with arrays and I'm wonder.. what's diffrences between those two lines.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:someArray];
```

and

```
NSArray *array = [someArray copy];
```

Which of it is faster? What in case we have `NSMutableArray` and `mutableCopy`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Which of it is faster?

Don't worry about it. Premature optimization.

The main difference: the first approach results in an autoreleased "copy" that you don't own and don't have to release, while you do own the object created on the second line.
Both arrays will be immutable, by the way.

Comment: What about with ARC?

Comment: I'd say with ARC use the second, so it's not autoreleased, and therefore not kept around until the autorelease pool is flushed. But again, unless you are creating lots of arrays inside the same runloop (or inside a @ autoreleasepool), that's premature optimization :)

Comment: which one should we use?

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the other answers, also note, that when `someArray` is nil,
the first line will make `array` point to an empty array and the second will make
it point to nil. This might be an important difference, especially in mutable arrays.

Comment: which one should we use?

Answer (score 7):

The difference between the two is that the latter will be retained. The former will be autoreleased.

Both versions make a shallow copy of the array.

```
NSMutableArray *notMutableReally = [NSArray arrayWithArray:aMutableArray];
```

Should give you a compiler warning as you will be trying to assign a `NSArray` to a `NSMutableArray`.

Use.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArrayCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:aMutableArray];
```

Which is faster? Dont worry, they are all far faster than the rest of the stuff you will be doing. Check with Instruments if you really care.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that `-copy` knows better how to copy itself (can do it more efficiently and maybe use a more adapted subclass of NSArray) while `+arrayWithArray:` will create a new instance of `NSArray` (well, in fact the concrete class used by Foundation for arrays) and feed it with the same list of objects from the initial object. Also it will add an extra autorelease.

So `-copy` is (very very) likely more efficient.

In fact for immutable `NSArrays`, `-copy` is just doing `-retain`, so it does not even bother creating a new instance.

Comment: This is not exact. A new array is creating when you do a copy.

Comment: You can try it with a simple test tool (not to mention that I have other very good reasons to believe I am correct here  )

Comment: @Julien as you seem very well versed in Foundation classes, what's the right way of checking whether an NSArray, NSDictionary, etc. is mutable? there have been discussions elsewhere already but no good answer found? (-isKindOfClass: is said to be unreliable, not sure about -respondsToSelector:@selector(addObject:) stuff?) looking for the proper way… thanks!

Comment: There is no way without bad hacking (and likely to be unreliable with future or past versions of Foundation. And in fact, you should never have to do that (or something is very very likely wrong with what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i ++)
{
    [arr addObject:@(i*1000000ULL)];
}
// MARK
// arr = (id)[NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];

NSTimeInterval t = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSArray *res = nil;
for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i ++)
{
    res = [arr copy];
}
NSLog(@"time A: %f", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - t);
t = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i ++)
{
    res = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
}
NSLog(@"time B: %f", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - t);
```

time A: 1.572795, time B: 1.539150, B [NSArray arrayWithArray:] always faster but time difference very small. **But if we uncomment "MARK" and get copy from NSArray instead NSMutableArray we will have other runtime A: 0.000473 time B: 1.548400 result: ~3200x times faster**

Answer (score 1):

One of them is probably faster. Run them a million times and see if anyone wins.

In case of `NSArray` vs `NSMutableArray`, an immutable array being copied does not have to actually return a copy since it can't change. However, if you have a mutable array, it would need to be copied since you could change the original. And of course doing a mutable copy always needs to return a new object.

In your entire app, the speed and memory difference is probably not going to matter compared to everything else that's going on.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, it's very different. Thanks to the new open-source Foundation for Swift, we know that whereas `init(array:)` creates a new array with the items given (if any), `copy()` simply returns `self`.

```swift
    public override func copy() -> AnyObject {
        return copyWithZone(nil)
    }

    public func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        return self
    }
```

<sup>https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSArray.swift#L82</sup>

```
    public convenience init(array: [AnyObject]) {
        self.init(array: array, copyItems: false)
    }

    public convenience init(array: [AnyObject], copyItems: Bool) {
        let optionalArray : [AnyObject?] =
            copyItems ?
                array.map { return Optional<AnyObject>(($0 as! NSObject).copy()) } :
                array.map { return Optional<AnyObject>($0) }

        // This would have been nice, but "initializer delegation cannot be nested in another expression"
//        optionalArray.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
//            self.init(objects: ptr.baseAddress, count: array.count)
//        }
        let cnt = array.count
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>.alloc(cnt)
        buffer.initializeFrom(optionalArray)
        self.init(objects: buffer, count: cnt)
        buffer.destroy(cnt)
        buffer.dealloc(cnt)
    }
```

<sup>https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSArray.swift#L116</sup>

So, obviously, `copy()` is faster, and now you know how they both work! <sub>(Just only in Swift)</sub>